# How it possible to break the while loop inside the child proccess

Tags: python, opencv, while-loop, multiprocessing

I've been coding the solution for video recording (cv2 usage) in the background to perform some actions and then stop recording.
cv2 lib propose solution to break the recording withing one loop by catching the keyboard interruption:

```
while True:
    ret,frame= cap.read()
    writer.write(frame)
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
   #  waiting for any key pressed
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == 27:
        break
```

But I want to split this flow into two methods: start() and stop().
As I need to perform some actions between start() and stop() I choose the multiprocessing lib.

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process


class Recorder:

    terminator = 0
    proc = None

    def func(self):
        while self.terminator == 0:
            print('func')
            time.sleep(1)
            if self.terminator == 1:
                break

    def start(self):
        self.proc = Process(target=self.func(), args=())
        self.proc.start()

    def stop(self):
        self.terminator = 1
        self.proc.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = Recorder()
    test.start()
    time.sleep(5)
    test.stop()
```

But as I understand the variable reassignment does not affect on loop inside the function that called iside the child proccess.

Is it any solution to pass the reassigned variable to child proccess or there is another way to solve the issue?

Making the variable 'global' did not help.

Comment: Multiprocessing provides a "Manager" class to create variables of simple types and synchronization primitives which can be shared between the processes.

Comment: you can remove the imshow, or you can have a bit of a mess there with waitKey and checking for start/stop from the outside

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz thanks, imshow is not nesessary in my case, thanks a lot. Moreover it creates additional problems when I run the script through ssh connection.
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display

Comment: @MichaelButscher I need to investigate this class, as I see it provides interesting solutions to optimize code in my framework. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiprocessing.Event for this.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Event

Just replace your terminator int flag with it:

```py
import time
from multiprocessing import Event, Process


class Recorder:
    def __init__(self):
        self.proc = None
        self.terminator = Event()

    def func(self):
        while not self.terminator.is_set():
            print('func')
            time.sleep(1)

    def start(self):
        self.proc = Process(target=self.func, args=())
        self.proc.start()

    def stop(self):
        self.terminator.set()
        self.proc.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = Recorder()
    test.start()
    time.sleep(5)
    test.stop()
```

Comment: But cv2 not write video with multiprocessing.Process class, only threading.Thread works.